# Can Telethon BOT delete its private conversations with users?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bots, telegram, telethon

I have telethon bot which I use it with bot token.
Can I delete the conversations that people started with my bot in private ?
How is that ?
is that possible at all ?

I tried to use document but it had something for client bots.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.